# How to construct a machine learning model for a boolean result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

Im fairly new to Python and machine learning. Im trying to come up with a few models for the following problem: I have a bunch of data in the form of an x-y-relationship that describes a positive and the same type of data that describes a negative.

Since the data is not uniform, sometimes I have 2000 rows describing a positive, sometimes only 200, I tried plotting it in a graph and running them through some Conv2D-,MaxPooling-, Flatten- and Dense- Layers.

Now that worked quite fine, the accuracy metric is between 95% and 100%, but my problem is how that model retuns a float instead of a true or false and I cant really discern how high the true accuracy of my models is. How do I proceed from there?

Also, what hyperparameters can I use to get a boolean return? And what types of models are suited for that problem? Thank you for your time.

Edit:
My Model uses the following Code:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(512,kernel_size=(5,5),activation="relu",padding="same",input_shape=(400,800,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(256,kernel_size=(5,5),activation="relu",padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(5,5),activation="relu",padding="same"))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The Output is a number between 0 and 1. I would like to know how to build a neural network that has a boolean output, or some other way i can get a proper accuracy on my test data.

Comment: It´s hard to know identify your problem is because you didn´t show your code. But based on your architecture (layers), I think you missed the last layer which is the activation layer (i.e. ReLU or sigmoid function).

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, you already have a model that works, you should be asking to understand how it works and how the output is transformed into a binary decision, there are already multiple questions about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output contains a sigmoid function, which means as you said your network outputs a value in the interval [0, 1]. You can treat this output as a probability distribution. Hence, if the output is < 0.5, then it is 0/false, if larger than 0.5 your output is 1/true.

Comment: I could do that, and while manually doing the validation I have been doing that, just doesnt seem right to manipulate the numbers that way. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: That is the way to do it. There is no other way to do it. You have a binary classification task and using binary cross-entropy loss. What this loss computes is exactly the probability distribution I mentioned. Your model learns a probability distribution, and from that distribution, you get the final label. There is no manipulation here. It is already what it is if I understand you correctly

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have a suggestion what other type of model I can use to solve the problem? I would like to tackle that question from a few directions.

Comment: I mean you can of course try different types of CNN-based networks. Do you mean something completely different than CNN or just some other Cnn network?

Comment: Something completely different, like maybe an RNN. Or some other kind of NN that can learn a y-x relationship. Im a bit lost with all the different kinds of algorithms there are.

Comment: Yes, you can use Rnn or lstm but I am afraid that they will be too slow. And Cnn work much better for images. Otherwise, if you somehow flatten your image, you can also apply SVM or similar classical algorithms but your inputs are 400*800, you if you flatten you feature vector will be of size 32000. If you have enough computation power and ram, this should be okay.